# JavaFX - Adjusting the ImageView in the center

Tags: image, javafx, imageview

I'm working on a Picture Viewer with JavaFX. 
My current problem is following:

Every time a new `Image` is showing in the `ImageViewer` (when the user clicks "Previous" or "Next") the `ImageViewer` shall get recentered in its `Parent` node, in this case it's a `HBox`. I'm using the `setTranslate` methods and it's working fine, BUT it doesn't work properly because the `ImageView` is taking different positions each time when a new `Image` was loaded.

I'm using this method to recenter the `ImageView`:

```
public void adjustImageViewBounds()
{
    double windowWidth = MAIN.getWindow().getScene().getWidth();
    double windowHeight = MAIN.getWindow().getScene().getHeight();
    double imageWidth = GUI.getImageView().getImage().getWidth();
    double imageHeight = GUI.getImageView().getImage().getHeight();
    boolean isFullScreen = MAIN.getWindow().isFullScreen();

    GUI.getImageView().setFitWidth(windowWidth - 50 > imageWidth ? imageWidth : windowWidth - 50);

    // 50 ~ 25px space on the left and right side

    boolean scrollBarVisible = false;
    Set<Node> nodes = GUI.getImageViewScrollPane().lookupAll(".scroll-bar");
    for(Node currentNode : nodes)
    {
        if(currentNode instanceof ScrollBar)
            if(((ScrollBar) currentNode).getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL)
                if(currentNode.isVisible())
                    scrollBarVisible = true;    
    }
    if(!scrollBarVisible && !isFullScreen)
    {
        // 80 ~ GUI.getInfoBoxAndImageView().getLayoutY() -> The Y position within the window of my whole ImageView container (HBox)
        // 65 ~ GUI.getLowerControl().getHeight() -> The height of the controlbar under the ImageView
        double newTranslateY = (windowHeight / 2) - 80 - (VISIBLE_IMAGE_HEIGHT.divide(2).doubleValue());
        GUI.getInfoBoxAndImageView().setTranslateY(newTranslateY >= 0 && (newTranslateY + 80 + VISIBLE_IMAGE_HEIGHT.doubleValue()) < (windowHeight - 65) ? newTranslateY : 0);
    }
    else if(scrollBarVisible)
    {
        GUI.getInfoBoxAndImageView().setTranslateY(0);
    }
    else if(isFullScreen)
    {
        double newTranslateY = (windowHeight / 2) - 80 - (VISIBLE_IMAGE_HEIGHT.divide(2).doubleValue());
        GUI.getInfoBoxAndImageView().setTranslateY(newTranslateY >= 0 && (newTranslateY + 80 + VISIBLE_IMAGE_HEIGHT.doubleValue()) < (windowHeight - 65) ? newTranslateY : 0);
    }
}
```

The method's working as long as I call it AFTER the `Image` was loaded, but it doesn't work when I'm calling it after setting a new `Image`.
Here is an example of when a new `Image` is set:

```
public void nextClicked()
     {
        if(PICTURE_INDEX < picturePaths.size() - 1)
        {
            String path = picturePaths.get(PICTURE_INDEX + 1).toURI().toString();
            GUI.getImageView().setImage(new Image(path));
            adjustImageViewBounds(); 
            PICTURE_INDEX += 1;
        }
     }
```

To solve this I've been trying to use different `Listeners`:

```
GUI.getImageViewer().imageProperty().addListener(newImage -> 
{
   while(newImage.getProgress() < 1.0)
   {
      //Do nothing until the Image is completely loaded
   }
   adjustImageViewBounds();
   System.out.println("End reached");
});
```

The end was reached actually, but the method didn't affect the `ImageView`'s position?!?
Also not working:

```
public void nextClicked()
{
   if(PICTURE_INDEX < picturePaths.size() - 1)
   {
      String path = picturePaths.get(PICTURE_INDEX + 1).toURI().toString();
      Image newImage = new Image(path);
      newImage.progressProperty().addListener((obs, oldV, newV) -> 
      {
         if(newV.doubleValue() == 1.0)
            adjustImageViewBounds();
      });
      GUI.getImageView().setImage(newImage); 
      PICTURE_INDEX += 1;
    }
}
```

Just for fun I tried this and it worked but it's not a reasonable solution of course:

```
GUI.getImageView().setOnMouseClicked(event -> adjustImageViewBounds());
```

To summarize all that confusing information:
I want my `ImageView` to get recentered by the `adjustImageViewBounds()` method, which works itself!
Recenter means to place my `ImageView` in the mid of the `Scene`, either the `X` and `Y` position.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: This just looks like you are doing way too much work. What is the structure?  ImageView inside ScrollPane inside HBox? And the requirement is that the image takes its natural size and is scrollable if its natural size is greater than the available space?

Comment: Hey James_D, possibly. I'm programming for a year with basic Java and I'm not that experienced at all, I'm learning JavaFX for about 6 months now. I appreciate any tips regarding my code!

The structure is following: ImageView and a VBox in a HBox and the HBox in a ScrollPane.

Comment: And the Image takes the width and height of the Scene's width and height. preserveRatio is set to true.

Comment: When I increase the Window's size, the Image is "growing" together with the Scene as long it's smaller than its "natural" size. And when I reduce the Window's size it's shrinking too, until minSize is reached. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the requirements. If you are setting `fitWidth` and `fitHeight` based on the scene size, it sounds like you are trying to make sure the image is always fully visible and as large as possible, in which case it's not really clear why you need a scroll pane. I'm guessing you want it centered in the case that preserving the ratio forces, e.g. some horizontal space around the image?

Comment: Ah, OK, so you are fitting the width of the image to the available width, irrespective of the available height, and you are preserving the ratio, so it may become taller than the available height (but never wider than the available width). And you just want to center it vertically if it is shorter than the available height?

Comment: The ScrollPane is needed, when the ratio between the Scene's width and height is not equal to the ratio of the current Image. This is possible, because the Image only gets resized when I change the width of the Scene/Stage! Forgot to mention it, sorry. I can send you the Jar if you want.(?) 
Yep, I want so center it and have some blank space around it.

Comment: No, I want to center it permanently. Even if the picture fits perfectly in the Scene, it's like to position the ImageView in the center, no matter which size the other components have.

Comment: Well, I'm not really understanding the requirements. I think you should be able to achieve what you want without translating the image view, etc, and just by using appropriate layouts and setting properties. However, since you have a mechanism that seems to work, if you want to use that but it's not working on a new image, I would log the values you are "measuring" (`window/imageWidth/Height`) and see what is not making sense. If the image is not measured, maybe try `Image newImage = new Image(path, false);`? That's a guess....

Comment: Thank you, I'll make a try.

Comment: Hey James_D,
I solved it! What a great idea with letting the layout managers do the work.
I did it with placing VBoxes withing my root container and giving them the "placing" information with using the setAlignment method.
Appreciate your help, just post an answer with suggesting me to use different layout managers, I want to mark your answer as helpful or whatever it's called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of moving the `ImageView` from the position that its parent determines for it, using `setTranslateY(...)`, it's almost certainly better to choose and configure a parent that will position it the way you want in the first place. Both `HBox` and `VBox`, for example, have a `setAlignment(..)` method that determines the overall alignment of the child nodes within the parent. The most "general" (i.e. flexible) predefined layout is the `GridPane`, in which child nodes are positioned in a grid, and can span multiple cells in the grid. Different columns and rows in the grid can have different widths and heights, and you can configure how a child node behaves if its allocated cell(s) have more space than the node's preferred size.

Some useful links:

An overview of all the layout panes is given in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102). A slightly old, but still useful, presentation on the overall layout mechanism is available on [parleys.com](https://www.parleys.com/talk/interface-layout-javafx-2-0) (registration required).